Add column name as XML node and join with other table

I am trying to query table column names as values of the XML Nodes and in the same node add values from the other table. I have found a code in other post that can create nodes from column names but I'm unable to add nodes from other tables.
My second problem is that I want to have node  with the original type of the column. But I have not found anything that could help me.

My sample XML should look like this:
<Product>
<ProductName>Product1</ProductName>
<Attributes>
    <Attribute>
        <Name>Attr1</Name>
        <Value>True</Value>
                <Type>BOOL</Type>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Name>Attr2</Name>
            <Value>1.0000000000</Value>
                <Type>DECIMAL</Type>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
        <Name>Weight</Name>
            <Value>155</Value>
                <Type>INT</Type>
        </Attribute>
</Attributes>

</Product>

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(ProductID int, ProductName nvarchar(40))
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (1, 'Product1')
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_WEIGHT(ProductID int, CurrentWeight int)
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_WEIGHT(1,155)
CREATE TABLE ATTRIBUTE_(ProductID int, Attr1 BIT, Attr2 decimal(28,10), Attr3 nvarchar(40), Attr4 int)
INSERT INTO ATTRIBUTE_ (1, 1, 1.0, NULL, NULL)

SELECT
ProductName
(
                SELECT(SELECT 
                      C.Name AS [Attribute/Name],
                  C.Value AS [Attribute/Value]
                 FROM  ATTRIBUTE_ A
                 JOIN PRODUCT_WEIGHT pw 
                    ON a.ProductID= pw.ProductID
                 CROSS APPLY (SELECT XMLData = CAST((SELECT a.* FOR XML RAW) AS XML)) B
                 CROSS APPLY (
                                SELECT Name = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)'),
                                       Value = attr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                                 FROM  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                                 CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                                 WHERE attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') IN ('Attr1','Attr2', 'Attr3','Weight') 
                             ) C
                WHERE a.ProductID = p.ProductID
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                FOR XML PATH ('Attributes'),TYPE
            )

FROM PRODUCT p
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Product')

When I tried:
(SELECT a.*,pw.* FOR XML RAW) AS XML)


It gave me an error: The transaction has aborted.
I have also tried:
SELECT
ProductName
(
                SELECT(SELECT 
                      C.Name AS [Attribute/Name],
                  C.Value AS [Attribute/Value]
                 FROM  ATTRIBUTE_ A
                 JOIN PRODUCT_WEIGHT pw 
                    ON a.ProductID= pw.ProductID
                 CROSS APPLY (SELECT XMLData = CAST((SELECT a.* FOR XML RAW) AS XML)) B
                 CROSS APPLY (
                                SELECT Name = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)'),
                                       Value = attr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                                 FROM  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                                 CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                                 WHERE attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') IN ('Attr1','Attr2','CurrentWeight') 
                             ) C
                WHERE a.ProductID = p.ProductID
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                FOR XML PATH ('Attributes'),TYPE
            ),
(SELECT 'CurrentWeight' AS [Attribute/Name], CurrentWeight AS [Attribute/Value]
FROM PRODUCT_WEIGHT pw2
WHERE pw2.ProductID = p.ProductID
FOR XML PATH('Attibutes'))

FROM PRODUCT p
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Product')

But it just duplicated Attributes node.
SQL Version 2019

How can I achieve adding nodes from different table?
How can I add another node with type of the column?


While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Sample data, in a consumable format (ideally DDL and DML) will help us help you. We have your attempt and your expected results, but no data, so this makes it difficult to replicate the problem.

Also which version of SQL Server? And does this really have to be dynamic, do you not know the names of the columns of ATTRIBUTE_ that you want?

@Charlieface SQL Server 2019 version, I know the names of the Columns in ATTRIBUTE_ table but the node value should have different name than the column name.

Some sample data also please. And what do you want because at the moment your sample table has the same attribute names as the expected output?

I have provided sample data. From the ATTRIBUTE_ table I want to retrive column names as  node value. And to  node I want to add data from PRODUCT_WEIGHT table but with a different node  value than the column name. I want to add node Weight and CurrentWeight.Value.

You are way over-complicating this. Unless you need the ATTRIBUTE_ column names to be dynamic, you can just use CROSS APPLY (VALUES to unpivot them, and cast them all to sql_variant, using SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY to get the base type.
You can also simplify the subqueries a lot.
SELECT
  ProductName,
  (
    SELECT
        v.Name,
        v.Value,
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(v.Value, 'BaseType') AS Type
    FROM ATTRIBUTE_ A
    JOIN PRODUCT_WEIGHT pw ON a.ProductID = pw.ProductID
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        ('Attr1',         CAST(A.Attr1          AS sql_variant)),
        ('Attr2',         CAST(A.Attr1          AS sql_variant)),
        ('CurrentWeight', CAST(pw.CurrentWeight AS sql_variant))
    ) v(Name, Value)
    WHERE a.ProductID = p.ProductID
      AND v.Value IS NOT NULL
    FOR XML PATH('Attribute'), TYPE, ROOT('Attributes')
  )
FROM PRODUCT p
FOR XML PATH('Product');

db<>fiddle
For bit columns you could special-case it to return BOOL and True/False.

Thank you, maybe I didn't say it clearly, but when some attribute doesn't have value I don't want to add this node

@user76864978 you don't say that in you question, you need to add it.

@user76864978 You can just add in a IS NOT NULL predicate, see edit
